# Wireguard site-to-site routing opnsense

Tags: routing, wireguard

I have Wireguard running in docker container (wg-easy) on VPS, the other machine connected is home server running opnsense.

```
VPS:
local network is 10.0.0.0/24
local address is 10.0.0.73
Wireguard:
local network 30.8.0.0/24 
local address 30.8.0.1 
Opnsense:
local network is 30.0.0.0/24 
local address is 30.0.0.14
```

I configured opnsense and can ping hosts on both wireguard and VPS networks.
Unfortunately I can't ping hosts on opnsense network from both wireguard container and VPS.

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**:

Routing below:

VPS:

```
x@x# ip route s
default via 10.0.0.1 dev enp0s3 proto dhcp src 10.0.0.73 metric 100 
10.0.0.0/24 dev enp0s3 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.0.73 metric 100 
10.0.0.1 dev enp0s3 proto dhcp scope link src 10.0.0.73 metric 100 
blackhole 20.0.10.192/26 proto bird 
20.0.10.229 dev cali3cdefa11b96 scope link 
20.0.10.230 dev calif02a59392ce scope link 
20.0.10.231 dev calif769328d198 scope link 
20.0.10.232 dev cali3b250d10ed4 scope link 
20.0.10.233 dev cali8c546dc9af0 scope link 
20.0.10.234 dev calie90ce798167 scope link 
20.0.10.235 dev calic318e29bd8a scope link 
x.x.x.x via 10.0.0.1 dev enp0s3 proto dhcp src 10.0.0.73 metric 100 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 
172.18.0.0/16 dev br-881f9d18b370 proto kernel scope link src 172.18.0.1
```

Wireguard container:

```
bash-5.0# ip route s
default via 172.18.0.1 dev eth0 
30.8.0.0/24 dev wg0 proto kernel scope link src 30.8.0.1 
172.18.0.0/16 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 172.18.0.2
```

Opnsense:
[image]

Comment: did you set up routing between these networks?

Comment: yes, I edited the question with routing attached